# Programmatically detect if Windows Media Player is installed

Tags: c++, windows, installation, media-player, detection

Anybody have any advice on how to programmatically detect if Windows Media Player is installed?

I know about the registry setting look up, but don't trust it since it's more than a little misleading (uninstalled may not remove it).  And I've considered just launching a video, but an error could be caused by something other than Media Player not being installed, so it's not conclusive either.

Ideally, I'd prefer a solution which could be used from both my C++ application AND my [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) installer.  But my the C++ app is the most important, I'm willing to live with the registry hack in the installer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the `IsInstalled` value under key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95}`. It is `1` if installed, `0` otherwise.

See [Detecting Windows Media Player from an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562731%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This is awesome, but is it documented anywhere that this value is actually set to 0 on uninstall?

Comment: I've ever tested uninstalling WMP 9 in My VM, and it was indeed `IsInstalled` set to `0`. Since the year of the MSDN documentation is 2010, I'm sure this behaves the same at least until WMP 12.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me add. From the MSDN link provided, the newer component id {6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6} has values for IsInstalled AND Enabled. Since legacy WMP is now disabled by default in Windows 11, you have to check both values.

Answer (score 2):

(You don't say whether you're checking for an embeddable (i.e. OCX) player to embed in your app or the EXE to launch extenally from your app.)

How about checking the HRESULT on CoCreateInstance against CLSID {22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95} / ProgID "MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.1" in your app? (CLSIDs from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676121.aspx)

In your installer just check for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95}, and perhaps also that the path at the InprocServer32 subkey exists.

Answer (score 2):

If the uninstall fails to remove both the EXE and the registry entry then I highly doubt it uninstalled anything...

So, I would suggest you check the registry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\` and if it exists, grab the value of the `Installation Directory` or `Installation DirectoryLFN` (default is `%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player`) and check that `wmplayer.exe` exists within that directory. If it does, then you will know that WMP is installed.

Comment: I like that idea of checking the installed app via the path in the registry.  +1